# MySQL Crontab Check

Tags: server, bash, scripts, mysql, cron

I have a serverpilot.io server running from digitalocean (1gb Ram), MySQL will crash once a week, the stats say the server is using ~256 mb out of 1 gb, but mysql will crash saying out of memory....

To solve this I found this script:

```
service mysql status| grep 'mysql start/running' > /dev/null 2>&1

#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" =~ "start/running" ]]
then
  /usr/sbin/service mysql start
fi
```

It works when I run it direct `bash /srv/mysql.sh`.

I have also run `chmod +x /srv/mysql.sh`

I have also tried:

```
* * * * * sh /srv/mysql.sh

* * * * * bash /srv/mysql.sh

* * * * * /usr/bin/sh /srv/mysql.sh

* * * * * /srv/mysql.sh
```

I am getting this email anytime it runs and mysql is not starting as it should

```
/srv/mysql.sh: 4: /srv/mysql.sh: [[: not found
```

when I run 'service mysql stop' and check with 'service mysql status' the mysql service remains stopped and non functional.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Edit 1: I added `>>/srv/cronlog.log 2>&1` to the end of the crontab line

and I am getting this:

```
/srv/mysql.sh: 5: /srv/mysql.sh: [[: not found
/srv/mysql.sh: 5: /srv/mysql.sh: [[: not found
/srv/mysql.sh: 5: /srv/mysql.sh: [[: not found
/srv/mysql.sh: 5: /srv/mysql.sh: [[: not found
```

Edit 2: I changed to `* * * * * bash /srv/mysql.sh >>/srv/cronlog.log 2>&1`

```
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.
 * Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly.
```

Mysql is still stopped in testing

Edit 3: Tail of crontablog.log

```
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.
```

Comment: Which of those lines are you using right now?

Comment: I have updated the question:

Edit 2: I changed to * * * * * bash /srv/mysql.sh >>/srv/cronlog.log 2>&1

 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
   ...done.
 * Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly.
Mysql is still stopped in testing

Comment: I only have one instance of mysql running

Comment: How do you edit your cronjob or which file do you edit?

Comment: crontab -e (it opens nano)

Comment: not sure if it helps, but I think, that #!/bin/bash should be the first line in your script...

Comment: I added it and it did the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In searching around I came across a better script and decided to try it, and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" =~ "start/running" ]]
then
    echo "MySQL restarted" | mail -s "Email Subject" email@domain.com
    sudo service mysql start
fi
```

More info can be found here http://cssjockey.com/how-to-create-a-cron-job-to-start-mysql-if-it-stops/